# Design Pattern to implement a settable JavaScript Module variable

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, modules, ecmascript

I am writing a client to talk to a server API in JavaScript. I have an OOP background but am trying to embrace modern EcmaScript.

So I started with this:

customerApi.js:

```
const baseUrl = "http://myapi";
export const getCustomers = () => { /* get customer code */ }
export const addCustomer = cust => { /* add customer code */ }
export const deleteCustomer = id => { /* delete customer code */ }
```

All the functions use the `baseUrl` variable.

Now I want to refactor so that the code that uses the customerApi module sets/passes in the baseUrl.  I have come up the following-

Make it a class:

```
export default class customerApi {
  constructor(baseUrl) {
   this._baseUrl  baseUrl;
  }
  getCustomers = () => { /* get customer code */ }
  addCustomer = cust => { /* add customer code */ }
  deleteCustomer = id => { /* delete customer code */ }
}
```

Pass the base URL into every method:

```
export const getCustomers = (baseUrl) => { /* get customer code */ }
export const addCustomer = (baseUrl,cust) => {  /* delete customer code */ }
export const deleteCustomer = (baseUrl,id) => {  /* add customer code */ }
```

Wrap in a function.  I think this provides the client code the best API as you don't need to instantiate or pass the URL.

```
const moduleFn = baseUrl => (
  return {
    getCustomers: () => { /* get customer code */ }
    addCustomer: (cust) => {  /* add customer code */ }
    deleteCustomer: (id) => {  /* delete customer code */ }
  }
)
export default moduleFn;
```

What is the preferred/most common pattern to implement a "settable" variable on a module? Is there a better pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the URL into every method probably makes for an inconvenient user interface.

Your other proposed solutions (a class, an outer function) are both perfectly fine. They are also absolutely identical for all practical purposes. For users of your API they differ merely in whether they have to use the `new` keyword.